# How to show ffmpeg progress with kdialog?

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, kde, ffmpeg, dialog

I have found here [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186595/341192) a script that provides a GUI interaction in order to trim/cut media files. I have tried to improve it a bit. Now it involves a file picker to select the file, a timestamp window to set the start and end points, a progress bar during the process, and a confirmation message at the end of the process.

But because I am in KDE/Kubuntu I have also tried to use only `kdialog` instead of `yad` or `zenity`, without much success. I have succeeded in using `kdialog` for the file picker and the end message, but the timestamp window is created with `yad` (a `zenity` fork) and for the progress bar I have used `zenity`.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
INPUT=$(kdialog --getopenfilename ~/Videos/ '*.m4a *.ogg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.aac *.flac *.avi *.mkv *.mp4')

eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1
DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))

ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT" | zenity --progress --pulsate --text="Running" --percentage=1 --auto-close --auto-kill

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
kdialog --msgbox "Process completed successfully!"
  else
kdialog --msgbox "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!"
fi
```

Looking into `kdialog` help, it seems there isn't a way to make a timestamp window with `kdialog` (but that is another question that I'm not asking here: I want to ask these questions separately).

What I want to ask here is *how to create a progressbar dialog with `kdialog` for the `ffmpeg` process*, given that `kdialog --help all` says:

```
--progressbar <text>                 Progress bar dialog, returns a D-Bus
                                       reference for communication
```

I gather that means the use of `qdbus`/`dbus` options like these [here](https://develop.kde.org/docs/administration/kdialog/#progress-dialogs):

```
dbusRef=`kdialog --progressbar "Initializing" 4`
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 1
qdbus $dbusRef setLabelText "Thinking really hard"
sleep 2
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 2
sleep 2
qdbus $dbusRef setLabelText "Thinking some more"
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 3
sleep 2
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 4
sleep 2
qdbus $dbusRef close
```

But I don't know how to adjust/integrate such options with that script so that it relates to the `ffmpeg` process.

With a line like `kdialog --progressbar "Running"`
I can make `kdbus` show a "dead" window during the process, which doesn't even close when that's over and nothing more. (No "progress" seems to be represented there.)

[image]